# Find dimension of surface arc in blueprint given instructions

Tags: metallurgy, technical-drawing, drawings

I'm trying to find the dimension for the surface arc as shown here as **L**:
[image]

It doesn't provide the dimension directly, instead it says:
`Offset surface "K" .077 from point "J". Then grind at "L" to .076`

Length of surface **K** is .149

I didn't understand how can I obtain the depth or width dimension for surface **L**.

What I tried is to from point **J** add length of the surface **K** plus the .077 and then set the distance of the left edge of **L** to this point to .076, but I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: what "dimension" are you trying to understand?  You have the radius of the grind (1 1/4), the depth of it (.08 - .076), and its location (1.00 from that edge next to K).  The width is whatever it comes out to when you grind the thickness at centerline to .076.

Comment: @TigerGuy It seems that `Offset surface "K" .077 from point "J".`  would be a necessary step to obtain the depth or width of "L". This is because it says `Offset surface "K" .077 from point "J".` first and also on left bottom it says `Gage location for dimension .076`, which is same dimension that appears on `Then grind at "L" to .076`. If `Offset surface "K" .077 from point "J".` is not used to obtain "L", then I think it makes no sense to have this information.